# Passwords and Keys freezes when attempting to sync PGP keys

Tags: 22.04, seahorse, keyserver

When attempting to sync PGP keys through the Passwords and Keys application (Seahorse) on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS the app freezes every time. I click the GnuPG keys tab, then the hamburger menu, then
"Sync and publish keys...". After selecting my keyservers I click the "sync" button and a popup window opens me telling me that the keys are synchronizing. After about 3 seconds, I receive the Ubuntu app crash notice asking me to either force quit or wait for the application to respond.
I've tried removing, purging, and reinstalling the application through apt, but this hasn't worked. The keyservers are valid as they are the same on my other computer (same Ubuntu version), and additionally invalid servers are handled.
`debsums seahorse` shows no issues with the app's filesystem.

Any idea how I can fix this? I know how to sync keys via bash but would like to have a working GUI as well.